# Вызвать событие "Click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

Я разрабатываю расширения, которые добавляют код js в сторонний сервис и автоматически заполняют форму для клиента.

Мне нужно вызвать **клик** по конкретному элементу на сайте, я перепробовал все варианты запуска событий и не нашел решения. Может кто знает, какие еще есть варианты вызова **Click**?

Сайт реализован на **knockoutjs** и здесь находится html-компонент этого элемента (возможно, это будет полезно)

```
<div role="treeitem" class="fxc-dropdown-option msportalfx-tooltip-overflow fxs-portal-hover" data-bind="&quot;attr&quot;:{&quot;aria-selected&quot;:ko.unwrap($disabled) ? null : $ctl._isSelected($data.value).toString(),&quot;id&quot;:$ctl._assignId(),&quot;aria-disabled&quot;:$disabled,&quot;aria-label&quot;:ko.unwrap($data.ariaLabel) || null},&quot;css&quot;:{&quot;fxc-dropdown-option-disabled&quot;:$disabled,&quot;fxs-portal-hover&quot;:!ko.unwrap($disabled),&quot;fxs-portal-selected&quot;:$ctl._isSelected($data.value)}" aria-selected="false" id="">
```

Также те функции которые я использовал и они не помогли (Проблема точно не связана с селектором)

```
selector.click();
$(selector).click();
$(selector).change();
$(selector).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: document.querySelector('selector').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('clicked')});

document.querySelector('#a').click();
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Вот так можно на любой элемент "ткнуть" :) Может быть у тебя там какая-то особенная ситуация, конечно. Но программно вот так можно что угодно кликнуть.

Comment: Спасибо, но это решения я упомянул в описании как нерабочие(

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используется класс **[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event)**

```js
const event = new Event('click')
const dropdownEl = document.querySelector('.dropdown')

dropdownEl.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Dropdown clicked!'))
dropdownEl.dispatchEvent(event)
```

```html
<button class="dropdown">Click At Me!</button>
```

Тут хорошо описано: 
https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events